# Trouble installing Kyoto Tycoon - Java. Maven failing

Tags: maven, kyotocabinet

I've downloaded Kyoto Tycoon via:
hxxps://bitbucket.org/EP/kyototycoon-java

When running mvn install I get plenty of warnings telling me it couldn't find several files:

http://pastebin.com/znpJ3d5n

When I first started running the install I was getting a lot of failures and no errors. After blindly going around and trying to install things separately, the output now looks like this. I have no experience with Maven so editing the pom.xml file is out of the question. I've tried using the ignore tests and compiling, and I get few jar files. This allows me to compile "Example.java" using:

```
javac -cp .:target/kyototycoon-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar Example.java
```

I then try to run the code using:

```
java -cp .:target/kyototycoon-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar Example
```

but I get an runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/finagle/Codec
    at kyototycoon.SimpleKyotoTycoonClient.<init>(SimpleKyotoTycoonClient.java:16)
    at Example.main(Example.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.finagle.Codec
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 2 more
```

I'm assuming this all comes back the the maven install failing, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any direction is appreciated. There doesn't seem to be a large support group for Kyoto.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this same issue, I found that JAR files I needed were being created. They were being stored in ~/.m2/repository/kyototycoon/kytotycoon/. I created a disgusting looking classpath that included all of these JAR files and this allowed me to compile AND run the Example.java file.

Answer (score 0):

If "editing the pom file is out of the question" I'd strongly recommend steering clear of Maven.

In any case, you can [install local jars to your repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html) if the artifact isn't available from any repository.